# Javascript not loading in on XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

So for clarity, here's how my 'website' works:

1. I load a HTML File (index.html)
2. Javascript (index.js) checks whether the user is authenticate (not necessarily relevant here)
3. Javascript (index.js) sends a XMLHttpRequest to a php file on the server which checks authentication and then returns a HTML file (result.html) to be included in the index.html file.

My Issue is that the the returned HTML file/content (result.html) needs a seperate Javascript file (let's call it result.js), but it does not seem to be loaded in when result.html is being loaded/returned. The CSS file hoever is being loaded in.

How do I circumvent the issue? Or am I just simply doing something wrong?
Hope this question is clear enough!

Here are the mentioned files:

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de">
    <head>
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="initDoc()">
      <div id "content-loader">
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

index.js:

```
function initDoc(){
    document.getElementById("content-loader").innerHTML = null;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("content-loader").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
            if (this.status == 404) {document.getElementById("content-loader").innerHTML = "Doc not found";}
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "/php/authentication.php?var=" + "examplevar");
    xhttp.send();
}
```

result.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de">
    <head>
      <script src="js/result.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/result.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     Content here
    </body>
  </html>
```

result.js doesn't really matter as it doesn't get loaded in..

Comment: change your `<div id "content-loader">` to <div id="content-loader">

Comment: Consider using `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: javascript never parse script after if found error... ```document.getElementById("content-loader").innerHTML = null;```

Comment: Is there any reason to not include js/result.js file from index.html?
And I don't think it as a good idea entire html file where authentication is required based on JS logic.

Comment: @RashodChamikaraBandara I tried to do so, but sadly in the included HTML i use a button with an onclick action. That works, but when i tried to set document.getElementById("btn").disabled = 1; it just throws a nullpointer exception.
That's the main issue I'm having.